# how to write implementation of stack based arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

Describe an effcient implementation of a stack based on an ArrayList. Characterize the running time of the stack operations for a stack containing n elements

Comment: Please do your own homework.

Comment: ["3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having solving it**."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: i did but i don't know how to write the stack implementation so i need help with it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically to push, ArrayList.add(). To pop, ArrayList.get(ArrayList.size()-1) and ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.size()-1)

These will be methods in your stack class, and its property will be an ArrayList

Comment: Can I get a star please? Doesn't look like anyone else is going to answer